# Debug.WriteLine overloads seem to conflict

Tags: c#, .net, overloading

In C#.Net, `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` has several overloads, including these two:

```
//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190153.aspx
public static void WriteLine(string format, params Object[] args);

//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w33ay0x.aspx
public static void WriteLine(string message, string category);
```

My intention is to call the first one with:

```
Debug.WriteLine("The path is {0}", myObj.myPath);
```

But it appears that I'm actually calling the second overload, because it is a more exact match.

Is there a simple way to indicate that I want the first one?

My best attempts so far are:

```
Debug.WriteLine("The path is {0}", new object[]{myObj.myPath});
Debug.WriteLine("The path is {0}", myObj.myPath, "");
```

But neither of these looks very elegant.

Comment: This is a golden example of why overloads should always be semantically identical. If two methods have different behaviors, they should have different names.

Overloads are fine to simulate default or variadic parameters, or if there are optimized special cases. However, they should always be identical in behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Debug.WriteLine("The path is {0}", (object)myObj.myPath);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is somewhat annoying. Yes, there is a better way. I use `Debug.Print` ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.print.aspx)) which has the same effect but fewer overloads. It is easier than trying to watch for when you might be passing two strings to `WriteLine` and casting to `object` and less typing too. Example:

```
Debug.Print("The path is {0}", myObj.myPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid using the overload, and just pass the formatted string:

```
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("The path is {0}", myObj.myPath));
```

Answer (score 1):

For lazy typers, like myself, I just use

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline("Hello {0}", "World", 1);
```

The extra parameter forces the correct overload, and is completely benign.

Comment: You're a 'lazy typer' but you're the only one who wrote the fully qualified namespace? 8)

Answer (score 0):

> My intention is to call the first one with:

The first one is not getting called because incase of string explicit overload takes precedence. This is what MSDN has to say about it.

> The paramskeyword in the syntax for this method
>   implies that the object array can be a single value. The exception to
>   this is the String object. Explicit overloads take precedence, so an
>   arg value of a single string will default to the
>   Debug.WriteLine(String, String) overload.

so inorder to call the first one you have to convert it to object so that explicit overload doesn't takes precedence.

```
Debug.WriteLine("The path is {0}", (object)myObj.myPath);
```